# This or That: jQuery Targetting

Tags: jquery

```
var $that=$('#id');
```

Which is faster?

```
$that.on('click',function(){alert($(this).length)})
```

Or

```
$that.on('click',function(){alert($that.length)})
```

In the former, you are targeting an element that has currently been targeted.
In the latter, you are targeting one that has been stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is faster since you are directly accessing the property of an object. In the former, you need to go through another jQuery request.

Answer (score 1):

`$that` will be faster. `$(this)` has to call the jQuery function and create a new object wrapping the DOM element. `$that` just returns a reference to an object that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$that` is faster than `$(this)`, as the latter will create another jQuery object instead of using the one that already exists.

However, in most cases the difference is too small to make a practical difference. You don't need to create variables all the time just to squeeze that last performance out of the code. You are not using jQuery to get the fastest possible code anyway.

Also, you should consider the difference in usage. Using `$(this)` in an event handler will always give you a jQuery object containing the one single element where the event was caught, even if the same event handler was bound to several elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $that=$('#id');
```

This is faster because everytime you use $(selector) you are searching the entire DOM tree. So by caching your Jquery object you are saving yourself from repeatedly searching the DOM tree.

Comment: You might want to clarify when you say `This is faster`, clearly you are talking about the code above the answer, but it might be confused with `$(this)` is faster.